# Filter checked rows in Datatables?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter, datatables, filtering

Is there a way to filter Datatables according to whether that column's checkbox is checked or not? I have categories with radio options of checked/unchecked/clear filter but can't seem to get Datatables to filter this.

http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/s827x/68/

```
$('input[name=lock]').on('click', function(){
        var col = '5';
        var chkbx = $('#multi').eq(col).find('input[type=checkbox]');

        // filter table
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'locked'){
            value = !chkbx.is(':checked')//'y'
        } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'unlocked') {
            value = chkbx.is(':checked')//'n'
        } else {
            value = '';
        }

        console.log(value)

        // filter accordingly
        table
            .column(5)
            .search(value)
            .draw();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is almost 2 years old, but I found a solution!

I just got this working after spending quite some time at it. Here is my solution:

(This requires at least version 1.10 of jQuery datatable.)

I have a dynamic dataTable, that is only populated once a user makes a selection on the screen. After the table is all defined, I have this code:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
            var val1 = $('input[name=displayIncluded]:checked').val();

            if (val1 == "included") {
                return oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.childNodes[10].firstChild.checked;
            } else if (val1 == "excluded") {
                return ! oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.childNodes[10].firstChild.checked;
            } else {
                return true; // include all lines
            }
        }
    );
```

The column with the checkbox is column 10 (it is hard coded, which bothers me, but it will have to do).

I have radio buttons set up with 'All', 'Included', and 'Excluded', all with name='displayIncluded'. The variable val1 gets loaded with the value of the radio button selected. If the checkbox is checked, selecting 'included' on the radio button will return true, or selecting 'excluded' will return false.

oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr gets the full object row of the table, where aoData gets a String array representation of it. Then I just get the column I want (10), and the firstChild is the checkbox input.

On the radio button, I have an on('change') function that calls this:

```
function displayIncluded() {
     $('#isbnTable').DataTable().draw(false);}
```

Hope this helps someone out there!